# Костыльный редирект на yii

Tags: yii, mod-rewrite

Дано:

есть проект на yii со стандартным для него htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Надо сделать так, чтоб при запросе определенного урла и всего, что за ним, например (/foo)

**site.ru/foo**

ну и всего, что происходило в нем, шел редирект соответственную папку (или на какую то другую. Например /bar).

Ну то есть, сейчас, если написать

**site.ru/foo/blabla**

я буду попадать, на контроллер foo и екшн blabla. А надо , чтоб в этом случае просто шел запрос на index.php в директории
**/bar/blabla/index.php**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/foo/\w+)|(/foo)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/bar/blabla/index.php [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Это выше или ниже существующего условия писать ? Спасибо
И еще вопрос: $ в конце разве не будет означать, что запрашиваться будет только /foo/blabla ?? 
/foo/blabla2 уже не сработает ?

Comment: @volkoff  подправил для всех условий что может идти после `/foo` это вставляется в конце существующих правил

Comment: Благодарю !  Очень помогли !!